# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value tabbarviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a "main" tab bar view controller and I am trying to pass variables to one of the tabs to be used in its own view controller, so in the view did load of the "main" controller I have the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let trendtbvc = tabBarController as! TrendsTabBarViewController

        trendtbvc.testText = "Test"

    }
```

and in the TrendsTabBarViewController I am just trying to set a test variable to "Test".

```
class TrendsTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    var testText: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(testText)
    }
}
```

But when i run it, I get the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I feel like this is going to be a simple answer and I'm missing something obvious, but I can't work it out. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: how you set  tabBarController propert

Answer (score 0):

This is where it fails: `let trendtbvc = tabBarController as! TrendsTabBarViewController`, check that you have set your tab bar controller correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. What do you mean by set your tab bar controller correctly?

Comment: How are you connecting tab bar controller with view controller?